# Django migration strategy for changing ForeignKey to IntegerField without losing data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I have model

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    target_field = models.ForeignKey(
        'OtherModel', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_('Target Field'),
    )
```

And i want to change it to

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    target_field_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Target field id'))
```

I want to do it without losing data stored in target_field_id by ForeignKey field.

I tried just to run makemigrations. But it deletes column and then creates new.

Much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Django `ForeignKey` fields store their value in an attribute with _id at the end, which you can access directly to avoid visiting the database.

I would suggest to not change the attribute name, just change `target_field = models.ForeignKey` to `target_field = models.PositiveIntegerField`. No data loss.